# shopware 6: auto-create migrations of plugin configurations in phpstorm

Tags: phpstorm, shopware, shopware6

Is there an extension or some like for phpstorm to create migrations of plugin data like configurations?

So we don't have to configure plugins for each environment manually.

Comment: That depends on what you consider to be plugin data. Plugins may use standard configuration fields which you would find within the general settings of a plugin. You could theoretically write an extension that uses the `SystemConfigService` to retrieve the config values for each plugin and store them in a suitable format. That extension would then also have to be able to read that stored data and reapply it accordingly.

If by plugin data you mean also the tables and data of custom entities that would be near impossible, especially with differing foreign keys between instances and the like.

Comment: https://sw-cli.fos.gg/commands/project/#shopware-cli-project-config-pull is also worth mentioning, it can be used for syncing configs